# Using folder IDs to delete folders in google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have no experience in coding however I found a script online to delete folders using folder IDs from a google sheet but it's not working.

Can someone please help?

```
function deletefolders() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); //or getSheetByName() if necessary
    var folderToDelete = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!A2:A4');
    var folderIDs = folderToDelete.getValues();

    folderIDs.forEach(function(id){
      DriveApp.getFolderByID(id).setTrashed(true);
    });
}
```

The folder IDs are in ColA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use `getFolderByID(id)`, but the correct name of the method is [getFolderById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid) with a lowercase *d* at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I can't express my gratitude for helping me solve this.